# POI formules in Excel not working when opening file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, formula

In my Java code, I'm filling a template Excel with the POI 3.7 library.

The first sheet is the data end the second sheet is a chart sheet. 
After filling the first screen with the correct data, I want my formulas in the second screen be recalculated.

The problem now is the formulas aren't standard refreshed. After re-entering the formula cell, the formula works fine but I wan't this already when opening.

Is there a way I can recalculate the formulas in java code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [evaluate](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluate%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) method from [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html). As the apidocs specifies:

```
CellValue evaluate(Cell cell)
```

> If cell contains a formula, the formula is evaluated and returned, else the CellValue simply copies the appropriate cell value from the cell and also its cell type. This method should be preferred over evaluateInCell() when the call should not modify the contents of the original cell.

Comment: Add the relevant textfrom the liked page because links can be broken.

Comment: I think the method you probably want to suggest is [evaluateFormulaCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29), which is the one that also saves the cached value for Excel to use